# Loading .brl rules into rulebase

Tags: drools, drools-flow

I am using a dsl to create business rules (.brl rules). How can I load the .brl rules into my knowledge base? How can I convert from a .brl file to a .dslr file???
I am unable to find any help on this. Or is there a different way to load brl files??
Please help.

Thank you
FMa

Answer (score 1):

If by BRL you mean the XML that the graphical tools use - then there is a BRDRLPersistence class, and a BRXMLPersistence class (both in drools compiler) that takes care of shunting that BRL to/from XML and to DRL (it doesn't go to DSLR).